# What's this vocal distortion called?

Tags: voice, effects

I've heard it called 'vox' once but nothing seems to come up when I search for it. I've tried replicating it with overdrive and sample rate changes but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: 'Vox' is just latin for 'voice' & commonly used as an abbreviation.

Comment: Your video is unavailable.  If the distortion is electronic then perhaps the singer put a distortion pedal between the mic and PA/recording device.  If it is organic, don't do it you're just going to damage your vocal chords.

Comment: The distortion is electronic, the song is True Shred Guitar by Sleigh Bells.